# How do you disable "emulate format changes" in Dolphin?

Tags: emulation, nintendo-gamecube, dolphin-emulator

I've been trying to emulate Mario Kart: Double Dash, on Dolphin, and am getting 10 FPS, and I was told by the state rating for the game to disable "emulate format changes." I have gone through every single menu on that program and haven't found it. Nowhere on the internet have I found an explanation as to where it is, and how to disable it, as it seems to be enabled by default. Help?

Comment: Isn't it referring to `Graphics > Hacks > Ignore Format Changes`?

Comment: Oh. Is it? Ha, anywhere I have found any reference to it at all, it is called "emulate format changes," but the wording is similar. Actually, that is probably what it is. Thanks.

Comment: This is the guide to how I set up Dolphin on my HTPC (i5 w/ HD7750) and Mario Kart works perfectly on it: https://dolphin-emu.org/docs/guides/performance-guide/

Answer (score 1):

As [Nolonar mentioned in the comments](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/150999/how-do-you-disable-emulate-format-changes-in-dolphin#comment203823_150999), this option is located under graphics settings.

***Graphics → Hacks → Ignore Format Changes***

[image: Ignore Format Changes]